# Open graph og:video Meta Tags content

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to set up a page which can be properly scraped by Facebook when it's shared/liked. The page will have a YouTube video associated with it, so in the content attribute of the og:video tag, should I put the YouTube video embed link or the actual youtube page link for it to appear on Facebook with the little "Preview" button that plays the video in Facebook?

Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: last time:
facebook changed rules for video and you need to change your share url for youtube video from http to https

Comment: is there any change in og tag implementaton.I am trying to implement the same og tag which was used earlier but it just adds description but without play option,when clicked on it redirects to the url.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a look at how Collegehumor.com does it and they include a bunch of stuff not mentioned in the Facebook API. Rather than just the following:

```
<meta name="og:video" content="whatever"></meta>
<meta name="video_style" content="whatever"></meta>
<meta name="video_height" content="whatever"></meta>
<meta name="video_width" content="whatever"></meta>
```

you also need `link rel="video_src"` and it helps to have `videothumbnail` and `og:image` too - I'm not entirely sure which one did it but there you go. That works :)

Comment: So what'd you end up putting in the `<og:video>` tag? The YouTube URL? Also, what'd you put in the `video_src` tag?

Comment: Daniel Hough, you didn't really answered your question here... You did not specify which URL you used for the video source.

Comment: The url I used, if I remember correctly - it was the URL of the flv file.

Comment: @DanielHough can you please provide a working Opengraph example  I mean the markup which would embed a real youtube video.

Comment: This is not the way it should be used. It should use the tags that YouTube is currently using, as been explained by @larsen161.

Answer (score 41):

You have two options. You can either set the `og:video` to https://www.youtube.com/v/YOUTUBECODE or set the `og:url` to the YouTube page.

In my examples, I'm embedding this video https://www.youtube.com/v/BQBjVr1iHH4 in the following page https://www.keithandthegirl.com/vip/bonus/episode/9/40/this-is-40. I would like Facebook to show the YouTube video whenever anyone shares my page on Facebook.

**Option 1: setting the `og:video` to https://www.youtube.com/v/YOUTUBECODE**

The meta tag will look like

```html
<meta property='og:video' content='https://www.youtube.com/v/BQBjVr1iHH4' />
```

Notice the structure of the YouTube URL is different than the typical URL. You will need to isolate the "v" query from the YouTube link and use it in the `og:video` link format I showed above. In my example, the value of `v` is `BQBjVr1iHH4`.

**Option 2: setting the `og:url` to the YouTube page.**

If you don't have the ability to isolate the `v` code, you can set the `og:url` tag to the YouTube page. In my example, it would look like this:

```html
<meta property='og:url' content='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQBjVr1iHH4' />
```

This will tell Facebook to get the Open Graph tags from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQBjVr1iHH4 and use that in the embed. That means the description and title will come from the YouTube page. However, if someone clicks the link, they'll go to your website.

In my example, if someone pastes the following link while I use the second option https://www.keithandthegirl.com/vip/bonus/episode/9/40/this-is-40 Facebook will see the URL is set to YouTube and query that YouTube link for the OG info. Everything will look like YouTube *except* the link will click to https://www.keithandthegirl.com/vip/bonus/episode/9/40/this-is-40

One other note: make sure to use **https**, not **http**. Facebook will not embed any non-secure video on the site.

Comment: I still see these meta tags on your page, but if I put the URL in Facebook, I just see an image preview of some stick figures, not the video...

Comment: The stick figures is the preview thumbnail for the video. If you share the link on Facebook, you should see the preview thumbnail and be able to click on it to play the video within. You have to actually share it to see the full effect of it.

Comment: Since you seem to know more about this than I do -- if you have a moment to spare -- I'm having trouble implementing this solution of yours. I've asked it as a new question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116133/difficulty-with-opengraph-for-facebook-embedded-video

Answer (score 20):

Here's what I found:

Using Facebook's Open Graph Protocol, Publisher can now use any video from any URL, as long as the URL has correctly formatted metadata in the  `<head>` of its HTML. Here's the list of information that should be in the `<head>`:

- Thumbnail image's URL:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:image" content="image_src URL">
  ```
- Video file URL (e.g. SWF, MP4, ..):

  ```html
  <meta property="og:video" content="video_src URL">
  ```
- Your page's URL:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:url" content="URL">
  ```
- Title:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:title" content="title">
  ```
- Description:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:description" content="description">
  ```
- Video pixel width:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:video:width" content="video_width">
  ```
- Video pixel height:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:video:height" content="video_height">
  ```
- Content Type:

  ```html
  <meta property="og:type" content="video">
  ```

Comment: Nice summary and should be the accept answer. Also, worth noting the original documentation is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#video

Comment: The video HAS to be SWF huh?

Answer (score 12):

You can see from the source code of a YouTube page, the `og:video` tag is in the following format

```html
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/k86xpd26M2g">
```

You can also see an example of the metadata used from YouTube simplified in the source code of the following URL: http://fb.stevelarsen.co.uk/example.html

You can read more about the Open Graph protocol here: http://ogp.me/

Comment: Note that these tags are not present on YouTube videos that have embedding disabled.

Comment: You're also going to want to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. More details in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17811187/461119

Answer (score 6):

```html
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"> 
    <head>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- [REQUIRED TAGS] -->
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/awesome.flv" />
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
        ...
    </head>
```

The link of the .flv file.... check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types

Comment: This links to a hosted flv video file but what if we want to share a youtube video?

Comment: This is not answering the question of how to associate a *YouTube* video.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumbled at the debugger provided by facebook please note the following:

When you are logged into the debugger you are under https session. In order to see your video in the debugging you need to add the secure url for video in meta. Adding youtube videos is easy, simply put the page url in og:url and it will work.

Spent and hour to come to this conclusion. Its too late I am too tired, wanna sleep now :)