# Facebook meta data for URL and video sharing

Tags: facebook, metadata

I have a page (URL) that visitors to my website can share on their wall. What I'd like is when their friends view the post in their feed that the link of the post clicks through to my website but that the post on their wall also include a video they can play directly in their feed.

I have been trying to get this to work with Facebook page meta data but so far no luck. I have added the following tags, is there anything obvious I'm missing?

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xyz" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My Page Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:url" content="/url/to/my/site" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCydfLwgXI" />

<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCydfLwgXI" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="640" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="385" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCydfLwgXI" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, very popular question.
Look at source: http://fb.stevelarsen.co.uk/example.html

Similiar topic: [Open graph og:video Meta Tags content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847496/open-graph-ogvideo-meta-tags-content)

Comment: Actually. This is not working. I had to unaccept the answer. the page you're referring to does show the video in the FB post, but the click through is to YouTube, not a different URL. I need to click through to go somewhere else.

Comment: Man, just change `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k86xpd26M2g">` for whatever you need :)

Comment: Man. That's what I'm saying. When you do that the video won't play in Facebook. It will load up an empty swf.

Comment: http://www.keepme.ru/upload/images/2013/02/22/6c073121eb8b69dab172bfd5b995e912.png