# Difficulty with OpenGraph for Facebook embedded video

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am having some difficulty implementing a solution that I found via my research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17811187/1467082) (the actual accepted answer is not helpful and has been downvoted to Bolivian).

**Problem:**  Facebook doesn't seem to recognize the OpenGraph meta tags that I have added to my Header.

**What I know (or think I know)**: It is my understanding that by adding some appropriate opengraph meta tags, the content, such as YouTube video, should appear in the body of the "post" on Facebook.

**What I have tried so far:**  Referring to the solution linked above, I have tried to implement this method.

> In my examples, I'm embedding this video
>   https://www.youtube.com/v/BQBjVr1iHH4 in the following page
>   https://www.keithandthegirl.com/vip/bonus/episode/9/40/this-is-40 I
>   would like Facebook to show the YouTube video whenever anyone shares
>   my page on Facebook.
>
> **Option 1: setting the og:video to https://www.youtube.com/v/YOUTUBECODE**
>
> The meta tag will look like
>
> ```
> <meta property='og:video' content='https://www.youtube.com/v/BQBjVr1iHH4' />
> ```

Further, I have attempted to disable plugins which may conflict with this -- any plugins which appear to add OG meta tags.

On the code side: I have hard-coded the following meta tags in the Header (this will eventually become a PHP function or something, but not until/unless I can make it work on a single post):

```
    <meta property='og:image' content='http://agnarchy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/2014-11-01-22.02.37.jpg' />
    <meta property='og:video' content='https://www.youtube.com/v/dt6pPdz5eqg' />
    <meta property="og:video:height" content="854" />
    <meta property="og:video:width" content="510" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="video">
```

**Observed behavior:**

All I see is the post's featured image. When I schedule or submit [this link](http://www.agnarchy.com/ambition-snowskates-10-year-edit/) to my facebook page, Facebook does not recognize the OpenGraph tags and does not render the embedded video as part of the content of this Facebook post:

[image]

**Desired behavior:**

This is at odds with the suggested method, which if I use the URL provided in that answer, I can see the embedded video player:

[image]

Comment: og:video need to point to a video file. You put a link to Youtube in there

Comment: @wizkid the example doesn't point to a video file,  just a youtube embedded on the site. As you can see from screenshots, it's working on that domain but not mine. ..

Comment: Or did you mean I simply need to include the embedded youtube on the page I'm linking to?

Comment: Do you have a link to the page it works on?

Comment: @wizkid is the keithandthegirl url in the quoted part of my OP.

Comment: Have you set og:type video on your page?

Comment: No I just have the one tag as indicated in the suggestion. If I need to add sine more tags that should be easy enough

Comment: The page you said it worked for had it. If it doesn't work for you look what they do and do that

Comment: Solid I'll give that another look and see if I can figure out out. Thanks.

Comment: @WizKid you may be on to something. I am still working through it but thanks to the [FB Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/), I found I have one more plug-in which was causing a conflict. If I disable that, then it renders correct.

Comment: I'm the author of the answer that you're referring to. I tried to take a look at your code but the OG meta tags are commented out. However, it sounds like you solved the issue with plug-in conflicts. Feel free to reach out if you're still having problems.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKhalili !  Yes, I believe I have been able to resolve it on my own; thanks in part to your original suggestion and some comments from Wiz above. On closer examination, I think that FB was simply returning a cached version of the page, and by using the Object Debugger (I don't do very much web dev, so I wasn't even aware of that!) I was able to fix it.  Next step for me will be making a nice PHP function from these suggestions. Thanks again!